# Why I always get 'false' value in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, javascript-framework

I have a function in **testFun.js**

```
var testFunc=function{

   var hasCar=false;

   return{
      checkCar: function(){
           for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
               MyCar.check(hasCar); //defined in following MyCar.js
           }
      }
   }

}();
```

Another function in **MyCar.js**

```
var MyCar=function(){
     var createCar=function(){
            //Create a car 
            //var car = new Car();
     }
     return{
         check: function(hasCar){

              console.log(hasCar); //PROBLEM HERE: fierBug console output is "false" always even CHECK_BUTTON has been clicked, why?

              var handler=function(){
                  if(!hasCar)
                      createCar();
                      hasCar=true;
               }
               //CHECK_BUTTON is a button on UI
               CHECK_BUTTON.click(handler);
         }
     }
}();
```

As you see in **MyCar** module pattern, when `CHECK_BUTTON` is clicked, I will call `createCar()` function, and change `hasCar` value from **false** to **true**.

The `hasCar` is defined in **testFunc** module pattern, and pass to `MyCar.check(hascar)`.

I have a fireBug console output inside `MyCar.check()` function, I expect that when mouse clicked the `CHECK_BUTTON`, the console output will be **true**, but I always get **false**, why?  I use `hasCar` to check is the `CHECK_BUTTON` has been clicked once or not, but if it always hold **false** value, I cannot know it. How to get rid of this?

Comment: I couldn't understand your flow, can you put some html code....?

Comment: CHECK_BUTTON is a button on the page, nothing else.... My question is on javascript... I just can not figure out why 'hasCar' is still false after I clicked the CHECK_BUTTON, as you see, it should be changed to true.'

Comment: what function are you calling on onclick of check_button ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primitive values are passed **by value** and **not by reference**.

Thus assigning `true` to `hasCar` inside the click event handler (in `MyCar.check`) does not change the value of `hasCar` defined in `testFunc`.

You could use an object instead:

```
var testFunc= (function(){
   var hasCar = {val: false};
   // ...
}());

var MyCar=(function(){
     //...
     return{
         check: function(hasCar){

              console.log(hasCar.val);

              var handler=function(){
                  if(!hasCar.val)
                      createCar();
                      hasCar.val=true;
               }
               CHECK_BUTTON.click(handler);
         }
     }
}());
```

Or define the `hasCar` variable in a scope accessible to both functions.

**Update:**

You will still get `false` in the console because `hasCar.val` is only set to `true` after you clicked the button and you never call `console.log` when you click the button.

Using a loop here does not tell you anything. More appropriate for testing would be, given your setup:

```
var hasCar = {val: false};
MyCar.check(hasCar);    // will output false
// now click the button
MyCar.check(hasCar);    // will output true
```

Have a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/pqvFH/).

---

**Further notes:**

- For better compatibility, surround your self invoking functions with parenthesis.
- You are adding a new click handler every time `MyCar.ceck` is called. I don't think this is desired.
- The structure of your application is quite confusing (at least for me ;)).

Comment: Exactly. I was in the process of writing the same thing :)